# Is there a shorthand way for a zero default operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, you can do

```
class Derp {
    constructor(config) {
        this.index = config.index || null;
        this.name = config.name || "derpy";
    }
}
```

This works great to set many values in an object. However, when the config property is a number with the value `0` (zero), this breaks down as `0` evaluates to falsy.

Is there a shorthand way to achieve the "default value setting" behavior without explicitly checking for undefined?

```
if (config.index !== undefined) {
    this.index = config.index;
}
```

Comment: perhaps `constructor({index=null,name='derpy'}) {
        this.index = index;
        this.name = name;
    }`

Comment: `this.index = (!config.index && config.index !== 0) ? null : config.index;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! [Destructuring and defaults](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values) made it into JavaScript at the same time as `class` did (ES6):

```
class Derp {
    constructor(config) {
        const {
            index = null,
            name = "derpy",
        } = config;

        this.index = index;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

or, if you’re feeling up to it, full use of destructuring to avoid one repetition of the property name:

```
class Derp {
    constructor(config) {
        ({
            index: this.index = null,
            name: this.name = "derpy",
        } = config);
    }
}
```

Some may find this hard to read.

Comment: is there a difference between this and having defaults in the function arguments? `constructor({index=null,name='derpy'})`

Comment: @JaromandaX: No difference! Putting it in the parameter list just gets a bit messy with enough defaults is all.

Comment: Yep, I can see how it would

Comment: Now my head hurts, trying to parse the code. I'll stick with an explicit check.